# 'Hamming' javascript test (Exercism) - matching letters between two strings

Tags: javascript, string, function, for-loop

Doing this 'Hamming' test on Exercism, and I'm struggling to see what's wrong with my function - would appreciate if someone could shed some light:

### Spec

```js
it('small hamming distance in longer strand', function () {
  expect(hamming.compute('GGACG', 'GGTCG')).toEqual(1);
});
```

For every character that doesn't match between the two strings sequentially, I want to add 1. So in this case, G===G (0),  G===G (0), A!==T (1), C===C (1), G===G (1).

So, as indicated in the spec, I would expect **1** to be returned.

However my function below returns **5**.

### My Function

```js
this.compute = function(dna1, dna2) { 

  var mismatches = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i <= dna1.length; i++) {
    if (dna1[i] === dna2[i]) {
      mismatches ++;
    }
  }

  return mismatches;

}
```

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect difference, you function should be like :

```
this.compute = function(dna1, dna2) { 

  var mismatches = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i <= dna1.length; i++) {
    if (dna1[i] != dna2[i]) {//if character not equals
      mismatches ++;
    }
  }

  return mismatches;

}
```

Comment: D'oh. Of course, thanks. I was 'matching', not 'mismatching'. And I overshot. Got it now :)

Comment: It's actually `i = dna1.length` not `i <= dna1.length` - my mistake. Plus should be `!==` no `!=`. Then the function works perfectly, as far as I can see.